# ServletResponse Redirect show application server address in 302 response

Tags: jsf, servlets, http-redirect

Why does a "hidden" 302 response is sent after a redirect showing my application server ip address and its port, (see the image above)

[image: see the image here]

This is considered as a sensitive information by the security team

This is my code

```
        try {
                    
        connectedUser = _authService.login(login, password);
      
        // redirect to index if user logged in successfully 
        Faces.redirect("index.xhtml");
        
        
    }
    catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        captchaRequired = e.isRequireCaptcha();
        throw new BusinessException(e.getMessage());
    }
```

How can i hide this?

I have to notice that the login mechanisme works perfectly

Comment: Please do not use images for text information here.

Comment: That 302 response is the redirect!  If you want to do a redirect, you can't hide the 302 response.

Comment: If i cant hide the response, so i must hide the server Ip and port, this isthe problem

Comment: Your server is apparently behind a proxy. You'll need to reconfigure that proxy if you want to hide all that information.

Comment: Yes, it is. but it's preferable to solve in the application, so i wonder if it's possible

Comment: I think that the answer is that it is not possible,

Comment: You can't hide your IP address untill you remove referer from HTTP response.

Comment: I just can't understand why before the redirection is done (and it's done properly), a 302 generic response is sent just before the right response, see the black rectangle in the image... so my question is how can i override this message or hide it ?

Comment: RomanC: Nope. This all is unrelated to the 'referer' header.

Comment: @BalusC i've tried same thing not being behind a proxy and I get same thing a generic 302 response showing the address of the page being redirected to